# Ubuntu 13.04 Terminal stops responding/freezes on launch

Tags: 13.04, compiz, freeze, gnome-terminal, effects

Ubuntu noob here, so I don't know that much about Ubuntu. I know how to get around, and what not, but I still consider myself a noob.

Anyways, on to the question.

Recently, in the past 15 minutes, I noticed the Terminal stops responding on launch. I don't even get text. Just a grey screen, then it goes dark (freezes), then I have to force quit it. The most recent things I have installed was:

-Virtual Box (No OS' yet, although I plan to use some. I haven't opened the application yet)

-Compiz Settings manager - This is when I noticed the terminal acting up. I understand that Compiz is a very advanced tool. Hear me out though. I was trying to enable the wobbly windows effect, but I forgot to install the essential effects for compiz. I did not mess with anything in compiz at all, I just looked around for the theme.

I think it's mostly compiz settings manager. Should I uninstall it and reinstall it? What gives?

I have rebooted my computer since, and I have seen no changes.

Thanks in advance, you guys are an awesome community!

Comment: This won't help directly, but remember, you always have the good 'ol `xterm` terminal emulator. You can reset the compiz settings with `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz` or `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`(found these two commands, not sure which one will work).

Comment: It didn't work :( Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You could try terminator, the multi terminal.

Comment: :UPDATE: 

I just realized that you can use other terminals for the same tasks (facepalm). Anyways, I got the terminal (Konsole) to run in a different DE (KDE). It runs fine in here, but not in unity. Every other terminal also runs fine in unity. maybe Konsole just doesn't like me? haha.